# How can I access a class from inside a css {} section?

Tags: html, css

I have been programing C++ for a while and now I'm studiying HTML and CSS. I'm wondering if you can access a class from inside another class as you can in C++. As an example, this is the problem I'm trying to solve right now (I'm trying to make an slider):

HTML

```
<img src="image1.jpg" class="images" id="i1">
<img src="image2.jpg" class="images" id="i2">
<img src="image3.jpg" class="images" id="i3">
```

CSS

```
.images
{
opacity:0;
animation-name:animation;
animation-duration:10s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@keyframes animation
{
0%
{
    #i1 {opacity:1}
}

33%
{
    #i2 {opacity:1}
}

66%
{
    #i3 {opacity:1}
}

}
```

So, what i'm asking is if there is any way to access a class (or identifier) inside of a CSS section {}.

Comment: Just to be certain is this the sort of effect you are after? https://jsfiddle.net/7g6xb87t/

Comment: Yeah, this is the effect I'm trying to get, but it was more just as an example of accessing a class from inside another class like this:

Comment: .class1{...} .class2{ .class1{/*Modify something here*/} } (Well it has more sense inside a keyframe as it has a variable outcome depending of the %.) Anyway thanks for the example, it will be usefull for this particular example =)

Comment: Not possible using native CSS. CSS cannot traverse DOM elements like C or C++ does. You can look into certain CSS preprocessors like SCSS (http://sass-lang.com/) to do something like what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Alright, this is what I wanted to know. Thanks you all for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

**CSS**

```
.class1 .class2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyPage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='class1'>
        <div class='class2'></div>
        <div class='class2'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='class2'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

With this, you apply the style only to the divs of class2 that are inside a div of class1, but not to the others

Hope this helps your problem

Comment: What I'm trying to do is something like this: 
 
.class1{...} .class2{ .class1{/*Modify something here*/} }, In the case of C++ you can do something similar but in a particular way that has to be known. I'm wondering if there's  a way to do it in CSS or if it is just imposible.

Comment: oh I'm sorry then, but i can't help you ;-)